# Static members class vs. normal c-like interface

Tags: c++, design-patterns, static-members, service-locator

Hey there.
After reading [here](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html) about the Service Locator pattern, it got me thinking wether a class with only static members really is the way to go, or if a normal c-like interace wouldn't be more appropriate. I see people throwing around the `class` keyword all the time when they don't even need it.
Example with static members class taken from the linked page:

```
class Locator
{
public:
    static IAudio* GetAudio() { return service_; }

    static void Register(IAudio* service)
    {
        service_ = service;
    }

private:
    static IAudio* service_;
};
```

Here's a way one could do it too:

```
// in .h
namespace Locator{
    IAudio* GetAudio();
    void Register(IAudio* service);
}

// in .cpp
namespace Locator{
    namespace {
        IAudio* service_;
    }

    IAudio* GetAudio() {
        return service_;
    }
    void Register(IAudio* service) {
        service_ = service;
    }
}
```

Both examples can be called exactly the same way with `Locator::GetAudio()` and `Locator::Register(...)`.
Is one of the above superior to the other? Are they the same? Are there maybe better ways to accomplish this? Or is it just about personal preferences? Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: This is a terrible pattern. I wouldn't take the advice of any site that recommends global variables like this.

Comment: @Xeo: the real question: why use a global state when you could provide regular methods with per-instance data ?

Comment: @Matthieu: Then you'd have to register the audio interface on every locator instance. Or did you mean why one would need such a locator in the first place?

Comment: @Xeo: I don't question the need for a locator, I don't know enough of your business case, but I would advise having a look at Dependency Injection and removing global state. Global state makes awkward programs.

Comment: @Matthieu: Oh, I don't use such a locator. I'm just eager to learn new stuff, and then I stumbled upon the linked page. Dependency Injection is of course to favor, but what about components, which get used *all* over the code, like loggers? Make every class derived from a `LoggableClass`? Inject a logger instance just everywhere you need it?

Comment: @DeadMG: That site just explains some programming patterns the author has seen in game developement, and since my main interest is the gaming industry for the moment, I just had a look there. :)

Comment: @Xeo: dependency injection would suggest injecting an `instance` of logger everywhere, yes. I'll readily admit that this is (at best) impractical, but as all patterns there is always a balance to find between the 'pure' theoretic view and the practical ground, which is what engineering is all about. In general logging can be implemented with a global Multiple Producer Single Consumer thread-safe queue or multiple Single Producer Single Consumer thread-local queues... but there are many other implementations and it really depends on the application at hand.

Comment: @Matthieu: > " **global** Multiple Producer Single Consumer thread-safe queue" aha! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposal with namespaces has a slight weakness in maintainability - if you need to change the interface for some reason, you have to remember to change both the interface (`.h`) and implementation (`.cpp`), or a mismatch may not be detected until link time. If you use a `class`, then the *compiler* can detect an error such as a number of parameters mismatch.

On the other hand, since the implementation (`service_`) in your case only appears in the `.cpp` file, you may be able to change the private implementation of the locator without forcing a recompile of code that depends on the locator. (Common class-based patterns can provide this same encapsulation.)

These are fairly minor differences. A public namespace containing functions is almost exactly the same as a class with only static member functions.

Comment: Since the namespace for the functions is not anonymous, I assume you mean the namespace for the variable(s)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the public `Locator` namespace. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

one good reason for using class interfaces is consistency.

often, there will be supporting implementation or subclass use of the shared data in the `Locator` class. therefore, it is preferable (to many people) to use one approach across their codebase, rather than combining namespaces and classes for their static data (since some implementations may extend or specialize the service).

many people don't like dealing with static data. some issues from the above examples are: thread safety, ownership, and the lifetime of the data. the data and the implementations can be easier to maintain if these are restricted to a class scope (rather than a file scope). these issues grow as the program's complexity grows -- the example you have posted is very simple.

namespace labels/aliases are more difficult to pass around (compared to types/typedefs/template parameters). this is useful if your interfaces are similar and you are using a good amount of generic programming, or if you simply want to implement tests.