# Unexposed private member variables vs. global variables in the source file

Tags: c++, global-variables, private-members

I am looking at some code in a company I am currently working at and I see a few (not a lot) declarations of static global variables in the `*.cpp` files (for example, to store a list of listeners) where the `.h/.cpp` files belong to a class. If a variable (static or otherwise) that is used only by class itself, I always declare it as private.

Is there an advantage to this over declaring the variable private? Is this bad practice? Or is this normal when declaring static variables that are used by the class only and nobody else?

> EDIT: In my question I asked about static, but what if it is a non-static global variable in the `.cpp` file instead of it being a private member of the class? Is that bad practice or considered ok? Any advantages in this case?

Comment: To clarify: You are asking if there is an advantage in using a *static global variable* over a *private static member variable*?

Comment: A static global variable that is declared in the `.cpp` file over a private static variable declared in the `.h` of the class

Comment: A non-static global variable in the *.cpp file would be even worse than a static global variable, because it could conflict with another identifier with the same name from a different file.

Comment: Maybe take a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977330/static-members-class-vs-normal-c-like-interface).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantage to this way is reducing the amount of "unnecessary" stuff in the *.h file.  This might slightly improve compile times and/or rebuild complexity when files or modified, and it may make the header file slightly easier to read.

(In my opinion, these advantages are small, and I will usually prefer the clarity of putting things that logically are related to a class in that class's scope.)

However, static global variables are deprecated and bad practice in C++.  If there is no other appropriate scope, an anonymous namespace should be used.

```
// Instead of this:
static std::list<MyClass*> MyClass_population;

// Do this:
namespace { // anonymous
    std::list<MyClass*> MyClass_population;
}
```

Comment: they were considered for deprecation, but this has been removed in at least the last two versions of the draft (n3225 and n3242). The C++ comittee recognized that it was far less verbose, as well as being C compatible. One could argue that since C++ brought overloads of the static keyword, it should be those overloads that should be removed :)

Answer (score 8):

From a stylistic point of view, this might, or might not, be okay, but style is subjective.

From a technical point of view, there are a couple of differences:

```
                             +----------------+-------------+
                             | Private Static | File Static |
+----------------------------+----------------+-------------+
|   Visible by includers     |       Yes      |     No      |
+----------------------------+----------------+-------------+
|   Accessible to friend     |       Yes      |     No      |
+----------------------------+----------------+-------------+
|  Accessible to all in TU*  |       No       |     Yes     |
+----------------------------+----------------+-------------+
| Require #include in header |       Yes      |     No      |
+----------------------------+----------------+-------------+

*TU: Translation Unit (roughly put: the source file after include resolution)
```

Technically, therefore, a `static` variable at file scope (or a variable in an anonymous namespace) can be *more* private, except that it is visible to all code that follows it in the source file (which changes the accessibility somewhat).

I personally prefer them for those *objective* reasons. I tend to keep my headers as empty as possible, because it makes changes with no impact on the client much easier (and I am the client most of the times!)

*Note: if I have forgotten differences, please do tell/edit*

Answer (score 0):

Static is meant only if you want the variables to be usable in that file, for private it means only in that class. In some instances they do about the same but I tend to choose static first because it is a compile time variable versus a run time auto variable. Although this does depend on compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

I do this usually when there is a function or variable that I want to share among classes which reside in the same file. In Java, I think this can be (I'm guessing here) achieved through inner classes. I think it's harmless as long as the external, user visible interface of the header file doesn't depend on them.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a `static` global variable: what you're looking at are `static` variables with file scope. (At least, my C++ teacher didn't call these global; I'm not sure what the standard calls these.)

However, they have all the advantages of global variables and all the disadvantages of globals except one: they don't collide with each other if they have the same name.

For example, the following won't link:

```
// in a.cpp
static int a;
int b;

// in a.cpp
static int a;
int b;
```

because the global symbol `b` occurs twice. `a`, however, poses no problem.

The difference with a `static` class variable is that those occur in the header, so changing, removing or adding them requires a recompile of all client code.

Answer (score 0):

Like you, I usually prefer the use of a `class static` in the `.h` file instead of a global `static` in the `.cpp` file.

However, there is *one* occasion when I prefer the global `static`. This is when it avoids the need to have a `#include` directive (to access the declaration of the `static` variable's type) in the `.h` file.